# Windows Terminal is not displaying PATH variable

Tags: path, windows-terminal

My windows terminal is not recognizing the PATH variables...

I was having trouble when adding new values to the path variable and it not working properly when I tried to run the applications I added, but when I went to check the PATH variable inside the terminal, it doesn't even know what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was having trouble when adding new values to the path variable and it not working properly, but when I went to check the PATH variable inside the terminal, it doesn't even know what it is.
>
> [image]

You are running the incorrect command.  You are attempting to use Command Prompt syntax within a PowerShell prompt.

You should instead be using something like the following:

```
$env:path.Split(";")
```

or

```
$env:Path -split ';'
```

Source: [PowerTip: Use PowerShell to Display Windows Path](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-display-windows-path/)

Comment: for outputting the PATH, this works. But I can't run programs added in PATH

Comment: I don't know why, but it started working after I did this command you showed me! Thank you!